# jQuery 1.10.2 how to fix Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

I don't khow how to call a function in jQuery 1.10.2. What I doing wrong?

http://prntscr.com/h23m4j

http://prntscr.com/h23mp6

```
<div id="#slider" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="list" style="position: relative;overflow: hidden;height: 100%;">
        <div><img src="<?php echo $this->paths->get_photo_url_by_photo_object($photo, 'product_page_small_image')?>" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="<?php echo $this->paths->get_photo_url_by_photo_object($photo, 'product_page_small_image')?>" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="<?php echo $this->paths->get_photo_url_by_photo_object($photo, 'product_page_small_image')?>" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="<?php echo $this->paths->get_photo_url_by_photo_object($photo, 'product_page_small_image')?>" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="<?php echo $this->paths->get_photo_url_by_photo_object($photo, 'product_page_small_image')?>" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="<?php echo $this->paths->get_photo_url_by_photo_object($photo, 'product_page_small_image')?>" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="<?php echo $this->paths->get_photo_url_by_photo_object($photo, 'product_page_small_image')?>" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="<?php echo $this->paths->get_photo_url_by_photo_object($photo, 'product_page_small_image')?>" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--suppress JSAnnotator -->
<script>
$(document).ready({
    $('#slider').simpleSlide.click(function ({
        column: 4,
        showButtonForever: true,
        cycle: false,
        autosliding: 0
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: are you trying to use the simpleSlide.js plugin (https://github.com/Masquerade-Circus/simpleSlide.js)

if so, perhaps look at the documentation and examples there for reference

Comment: i used example code from documentation, and this script don`t work

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Infinite-Loop-Slider-with-jQuery-SimpleSlide/

Comment: i need to used jquery 1.10.2

Comment: Was there a problem with the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a JSON object to `$(document).ready()`. As per the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), it takes a function as a parameter.

Also, you're making a somewhat similar error in the `simpleSlide` click handler (missing a parenthesis).

Therefore, you should fix your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').simpleSlide.click(function() {
        column: 4,
        showButtonForever: true,
        cycle: false,
        autosliding: 0
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of the `.click()` method is not needed here, unless you're trying to generate the slideshow when the container is clicked. Following [the example you provided](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Infinite-Loop-Slider-with-jQuery-SimpleSlide/) and [the examples on the simpleSlider demo](http://masquerade-circus.net/myPlugins/simpleSlide/simpleSlideExt.html), I would expect your function to look like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#slider').simpleSlide({
      column: 4,
      showButtonForever: true,
      cycle: false,
      autosliding: 0
   });
});
```

As noted in the other answer, you have some syntax errors in the use of `$(document).ready()` and missing parenthesis on the `.click()` function.